Unable to perform DB operation using HikariPool connection from a child thread
I am performing db operation (get a row value) using Entity and Repository. When the db operation is performed from the main thread, it works fine. When the db operation is performed form the child thread, I get the error 'No database selected'
Sample code:
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RTest {
    private final SuiteResultDBUtil suiteResultDBUtil;
    private final SuiteResultRepository suiteResultRepository;
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    public void callInNewThread() {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                suiteResultRepository.get(1L);  // -- this will throw 'No database selected' error
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}


Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Probably somewhere ThreadLocal or FastThreadLocal is used to conserve state. You could switch threads for DB operations.
